# DockerFiles needed for dpdk pktgen and testpmd images

Tags: dpdk

Hej all,

A new beginner in DPDK world ! I am trying to build a set-up with two k8s pods, one with testpmd and another with pktgen.

As a part of this I need to build Docker images for both the pods, all the DockerFiles from various source are outdated.

If anyone of you have latest Dockerfiles for pktgen and testpmd, please share or point me in right direction.

Thanks !

For instance here, I am using a DockerFile for testpmd image:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get -y upgrade; \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 wget lsb-release
ENV DPDK_VER=22.11
ENV DPDK_DIR=/usr/src/dpdk-${DPDK_VER}
WORKDIR /usr/src/
RUN wget http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/snapshot/dpdk-22.11.tar.gz
RUN tar -xf dpdk-${DPDK_VER}.tar.gz

ENV RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
ENV RTE_SDK=${DPDK_DIR}
WORKDIR ${DPDK_DIR}

RUN sed -i -e 's/EAL_IGB_UIO=y/EAL_IGB_UIO=n/' config/common_linux
RUN sed -i -e 's/KNI_KMOD=y/KNI_KMOD=n/' config/common_linux
RUN sed -i -e 's/LIBRTE_KNI=y/LIBRTE_KNI=n/' config/common_linux
RUN sed -i -e 's/LIBRTE_PMD_KNI=y/LIBRTE_PMD_KNI=n/' config/common_linux
RUN sed -i 's/\(CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_MLX5_PMD=\)n/\1y/g' $DPDK_DIR/config/common_base
RUN make install T=${RTE_TARGET} DESTDIR=${RTE_SDK}

WORKDIR ${DPDK_DIR}/app/test-pmd
RUN make
RUN cp testpmd /usr/bin/testpmd
```

It fails at "sed -i -e 's/EAL_IGB_UIO=y/EAL_IGB_UIO=n/' config/common_linux" as there is no config/common_linux folder in the latest dpdk build.

Answer (score 0):

`igb_uio` has been remove from dpdk source. You don't need disable that.

And now DPDK has replace the make system with meson and ninja. You can disable   drivers and libs with meson setup, for example

```
meson setup $(dpdk_src_dir) $(dpdk_build_dir) -Ddisable_drivers=net/vmxnet3,baseband/\* -Ddisable_libs=acl,bbdev
```

So you may need to rewrite the Dockerfile, install meson and ninja, change the configure process with meson.